# rxjs: switchMap ignores error

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm not sure if this is a bug in rxjs or I'm missing something. When returning an error throwing observable in a `switchMap` the error isn't thrown by the main observable.

```
export class AppComponent {

    constructor() {
        this.doStuff();
    }

    doStuff() {
      Observable.of('any observable').switchMap(() => {
        return this.oops();
      });
    }

    oops() {
      return Observable.throw('doh');
    }
}
```

Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/f6dgGe3qvwX1Myn3PRfR

There is no error thrown in the console. Why is that? I thought `switchMap` would just 'replace' the Observable with another?

Comment: There can't be an error as long as you don't subscribe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Observable chain is not going to do anything until you subscribe to it.

```
doStuff() {
  Observable.of('any observable').switchMap(() => {
    return this.oops();
  }).subscribe();
}

oops() {
  return Observable.throw('doh');
}
```

Note, that the projection function for the `switchMap()` can throw an exception and it'll be sent as an `error` notification. So you could also just use the following and the result will be the same:

```
oops() {
  throw new Error('doh');
}
```